# Point iTunes to restored content after PC crash

Tags: itunes, windows, restore, pc

After my PC died I have started to restore my data from backup.  I have backed up the entire iTunes folder and successfully restored it.  I do not put my content in the standard location...I do not put it on the Windows drive for example.  Now that I have reinstalled iTunes, how do I tell it to use the content I restored?  Right now it just shows all my music as existing on the cloud.

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and I have the latest version of iTunes.  I do not have iTunes match.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default location for the main mp3 file storage for iTunes, but not [easily] the location of the database files.

It is far simpler in the long term to leave the database in its default location -
`C:\Users\[your name]\Music\iTunes`
This is also a folder you should recover from your old machine & transfer to the new one, otherwise you will have all the music but none of the playlists, play counts etc etc. & will have to re-import all your existing tunes.

You can, however, easily change the main 'content' storage location.

Go to Edit menu > preferences > Advanced

The first section is 'iTunes Media Folder Location' with a file path beneath [presumably currently set to the default location mentioned above] & a Change… button to the right. This will allow you to redirect to your non-standard location.

[image]

If you still have the original database successfully recovered from your old machine, then to save a lot of additional effort, make sure you put your content folder in "the same place" as it used to be on the old machine, i.e., if it was in `D:\iTunes remote folder` then put it in the same place again, otherwise it will lose the connection to your existing tunes & again have to be rebuilt.

Comment: Glad to hear it ;)